# insert multiselect values into database from a foreach table

Tags: laravel

[image]

I have the table above whereby at the last column is a multi select dropdown where one can select multiple number of countries. i have a problem in inserting the select values of each row into the table my code to inser is as below

```html
<div class="container-flow">
<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm text-center">
<thead style="background-color:#00BFFF;">
<tr>
<th class="fixed" scope="col"> No.</th>
<th class="fixed" scope="col">Price List</th>
<th scope="col">Level One</th>
<th scope="col">Level Two</th>
<th scope="col">Level Three</th>
<th scope="col">Level Four</th>
<th scope="col">Level Five</th>
<th scope="col">Level Six</th>
<th scope="col">Level Seven</th>
<th scope="col">Level Eight</th>
<th scope="col">Level Nine</th>
<th scope="col">Level Ten</th>
<th width='150px' scope="col">Assigned Country</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $i = 1 ?>
@foreach ($pricing as $price)
<tr>
<td class="fixed_td">{{  $i++}}</td>
<input type="hidden" name="price_list[]" value="{{$price->id}}">
<td class="fixed_td">{{$price->type_name}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_four[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_five[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"   name="level_eight[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_eight[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_ten[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_ten[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td>
<select id="country_id" name="country_id[{{$loop->index}}][]"  class="form-control country_id" multiple="multiple">
@foreach ($countrys as $country)
<option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->country_name}}</option>
@endforeach  
</select>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>  
</div>
```

[image]

i want to end up with something like below in the database.The issue is getting multiselect values of each row

```html
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_four[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_five[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"   name="level_eight[]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_eight[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_ten[]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_ten[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td>
<select id="country_id" name="country_id[]" class="form-control country_id" multiple="multiple">
@foreach ($countrys as $country)
<option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->country_name}}</option>
@endforeach  
</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this this worked for me

```html
  $this-> validate($request,[
            'user_id'=>'required',
           
        ]); 
        $count = count($request->input('price_list',[]));
                     
       
        $permission = new Permission;
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        // $country_id =$request->input('country_id',[])[$i];
        
        // print_r(implode(',', $request->input('country_id')));
       
        
             
        $data[] = array(
        'user_id' =>$request->input('user_id'),
        'price_list'=>$request->input('price_list')[$i], 
        'level_one'=>$request->input('level_one')[$i], 
        'level_two'=>$request->input('level_two')[$i],
        'level_three'=>$request->input('level_three')[$i],
        'level_four'=>$request->input('level_four')[$i], 
        'level_five'=>$request->input('level_five')[$i],
        'level_six'=>$request->input('level_six')[$i],
        'level_seven'=>$request->input('level_seven')[$i], 
        'level_eight'=>$request->input('level_eight')[$i],  
        'level_nine'=>$request->input('level_nine')[$i],  
        'level_ten'=>$request->input('level_ten')[$i], 
        'country_id'=> implode(',', $request->input('country_id',[])[$i]),
        'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),     

         );
         }
           
        // dd($data);
           
        Permission::insert($data);
         return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Permissions Created Successfully');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to convert an array `[1, 2, 3, 4,]` into a string `"1,2,3,4"`

```
'country_id'=> implode(',', $request->input('country_id')[$i]??[]),
```

Your select input need to have a name attribute value ending with `[]` for it to be sent as an array.

example

```
<select name="country_id[1][]">
    //.....
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Set your select input as this

```html
@foreach ($pricing as $price)
<tr>
<td class="fixed_td">{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
<input type="hidden" name="price_list[{{$loop->index}}]" value="{{$price->id}}">
<td class="fixed_td">{{$price->type_name}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_one[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_two[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_three[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_four[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_five[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_six[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_seven[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"   name="level_eight[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_eight[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_nine[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_nine[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_ten[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_ten[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td>
<select id="country_id" name="country_id[{{$loop->index}}][]"  class="form-control country_id" multiple="multiple">
@foreach ($countrys as $country)
<option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->country_name}}</option>
@endforeach  
</select>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this one give implode(): Invalid arguments passed thats where am stack how do i pass the counter[$i]

Comment: @Mannu254 what does `dd($request->input('country_id')[$i])` give you. did you name your select as mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: this returns '1' which is the id of one country in the first raw [1,2,3,4] it should be giving me the entire first row array but you see its not looping inside the row array.

Comment: @Mannu254 Did you change the name attribute of the select ? how is your select input declared right now ?

Comment: have added my html code up there

Comment: @Mannu254 can you also include the loop around the inputs ?

Comment: No there is already a foreach loop for that which loops through users from database the input fields are the static fields

Comment: @Mannu254 Edited my answer, it should work just fine but i could have told you "it works 100%" if you shared the full loop surrounding those inputs.

Comment: @N696s i have shared the entire code of that page i have set thi name="country_id[{{$loop->index}}][]" in blade but how i do capture this in controller 'country_id'=> implode(',', $request->input('country_id')[$i]), doesnt work still gives offset error

Comment: @Mannu254 that should work now (edited the answer), if you still have issues, join me in chat, I'll be there for an hour  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243846/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-71842897-insert-multiselect-values-into-datab

Comment: @Mannu254 what do you get when you `dd($request->input('country_id'))` it should be an array of arrays

Comment: yes then i use the for counter to get specific array and implode then store in the db. the issue i have is that when i don't select the countries in some rows i get error Undefined offset: 1  because that row array is empty.the field its not a mandatory field . I thought of forcing it to set the value of the multiselect to 0 if nothing is selected to avoid this error but still have not managed the script

Comment: @Mannu254 that's an easy implementation `'country_id'=> implode(',', $request->input('country_id')[$i]??[]),`

Comment: thanks man yes that is what i wanted its perfect now

Answer (score 0):

I have another issue when trying to update the checkboxes

```html
 <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_one == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_one[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_two == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_two[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="1"{{($perm->level_three == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_three[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[]" class=" check" value="1"{{($perm->level_four == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }} ><input type="hidden"  name="level_four[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[]" class=" check" value="1" {{($perm->level_five == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_five[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_six == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_six[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_seven == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_seven[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"   name="level_eight[]" class=" check" value="1" {{($perm->level_eight == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_eight[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_nine == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_nine[]" class="check" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_ten[]" class="check" value="1" {{($perm->level_ten == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}><input type="hidden"  name="level_ten[]" class="check"  value="0" ></td>
```

it is not working issue being the hidden input how can i work without the hidden input since when i edit like check like tick the below column ten[![enter image description here][1]][1]
when dd($data) for that column i should get 111111111 but am getting 0101010101 when i remove the hidden it works well but gives offset error if one checkbox is not ticked

my update controller is like this

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    $this-> validate($request,[
        'user_id'=>'required',
        
    ]); 
    $ids = $request->input('id',[]);

    foreach($ids as $key => $value){ 

    $permission = Permission::find($request->id[$key]); 
    $permission->level_one = $request->level_one[$key]; 
    $permission->level_two = $request->level_two[$key];
    $permission->level_three = $request->level_three[$key];
    $permission->level_four = $request->level_four[$key];
    $permission->level_five = $request->level_five[$key];
    $permission->level_six = $request->level_six[$key];
    $permission->level_seven = $request->level_seven[$key];
    $permission->level_eight = $request->level_eight[$key];
    $permission->level_nine = $request->level_nine[$key];
    $permission->level_ten = $request->level_ten[$key];  
    $permission->country_id =implode(',', $request->input('country_id',[])[$key]??[]);

    // print($permission);

  
    $permission->save(); 
    }
    // return($permission);
    //  print($permission);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Permissions Updated Successfully');
```

what should i change for the update to work correctly
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8vIb.png